# Creating BIG multi-line characters

Tags: text-editing, formatting

Is there a function I can grab from somewhere that turns a string of text into a multi-line string of the same text.  For example "Hi" becomes:

```
 H  H   i
 H  H
 HHHH   i
 H  H   i
 H  H   i
```

I don't need it to do this 'on the fly' although that would be very cool.  I will settle for a defun that returns an array of strings.  I'm basically hoping someone has done the tedious part of creating all the characters at some point in Emacs long history and someone can tell me where to find it.  Anything else is gravy.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve never seen anything like that as an Emacs package, but you can install the `banner` or `figlet` programs and use them to get the result you want.

Comment: Hmm.  Install... Not really the type of solution I was looking for.  I think I'd create them all  myself before taking that route.  Not that using something like Https://www.askapache.com/online-tools/figlet-ascii/ wouldn't relieve me of some of the tedium but I'm hoping for an entirely Emacs solution.